# create new directory in spool

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a script to spool in a dynamically create a new folder 
here is my code

```
set feedback off;
set pages 0;
set term off;
column dt new_value _dt;
column mn new_value _mn;
select 'C:\Users\rjen01\Desktop\'||to_char(sysdate,'MON')||'\' from dual;
select to_char(sysdate,'ddMONyyyy_hh24mi')||'.csv' dt from dual;
spool &_mn &_dt;
select sysdate from dual;
spool off;
```

and it gives the error 
Cannot create SPOOL file C:\Users\rjen01\Desktop\MAR\ 21MAR2017_1227.csv

its because there is no folder C:\Users\rjen01\Desktop\MAR.So how can i create a new folder dynamically in spool command.

Comment: Create a folder in the batch file and pass the location to the script as a parameter.

Comment: You can't. SQL\*Plus is a venerable client with limited ability to interact with the OS

Comment: But I am able to create a file .i.e if the folder C:\Users\rjen01\Desktop\MAR\  already exists the file 21MAR2017_1227.csv gets created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`host` - Executes a host operating system command without leaving SQL*Plus.

I've change your example and now it's working.

```
set feedback off;
set pages 0;
set term off;
column dt new_value _dt;
column mn new_value _mn;
select to_char(sysdate,'MON')  mn from dual;
host mkdir &_mn
select to_char(sysdate,'MON')||'\'||to_char(sysdate,'ddMONyyyy_hh24mi')||'.csv' dt from dual;
spool &_dt;
select sysdate from dual;
spool off;
/
```

I don't know if this solution will be work in sqldeveloper.